# When MPI_Send doesn't block

Tags: amazon-ec2, mpi, send, broadcast, openmpi

I have used some code that implements manual MPI broadcast, basically a demo that unicasts an integer from root to all other nodes. Of course, unicasting to many nodes is less efficient than `MPI_Bcast()` but I just want to check how things work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>

void my_bcast(void* data, int count, MPI::Datatype datatype, int root, MPI::Intracomm communicator) {
    int world_size = communicator.Get_size();
    int world_rank = communicator.Get_rank();

    if (world_rank == root) {
        // If we are the root process, send our data to everyone
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < world_size; i++) {
            if (i != world_rank) {
                communicator.Send(data, count, datatype, i, 0);
            }
        }
    } else {
        // If we are a receiver process, receive the data from the root
        communicator.Recv(data, count, datatype, root, 0);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    MPI::Init();

    int world_rank = MPI::COMM_WORLD.Get_rank();

    int data;
    if (world_rank == 0) {
        data = 100;
        printf("Process 0 broadcasting data %d\n", data);
        my_bcast(&data, 1, MPI::INT, 0, MPI::COMM_WORLD);
    } else {
        my_bcast(&data, 1, MPI::INT, 0, MPI::COMM_WORLD);
        printf("Process %d received data %d from root process\n", world_rank, data);
    }

    MPI::Finalize();
}
```

What I noticed is that if I remove the check that the root doesn't send to itself,

```
if (i != world_rank) {
...
}
```

the program still works and doesn't block whereas the default behavior of `MPI_Send()` is supposed to be blocking i.e. to wait until the data has been received at the other end. But `MPI_Recv()` is never invoked by the root. Can someone explain why this is happening?

I run the code from the root with the following command (the cluster is set up on Amazon EC2 and using NFS as shared storage among the nodes and all machines have Open MPI 1.10.2 installed)

`mpirun -mca btl ^openib -mca plm_rsh_no_tree_spawn 1 /EC2_NFS/my_bcast`

The C file is compiled with

`mpic++ my_bcast.c`

and `mpic++` version is 5.4.0.

The code is taken from [www.mpitutorial.com](http://www.mpitutorial.com)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mistaking **blocking** for **synchronous** behaviour. Blocking means that the call does not return until the operation has completed. The standard send operation (`MPI_Send`) completes once the supplied buffer is free to be reused by the program. This means either that the message is  fully in transit to the receiver or that it was stored internally by the MPI library for later delivery (buffered send). The buffering behaviour is implementation-specific, but most libraries will buffer messages the size of a single integer. Force the synchronous mode by using `MPI_Ssend` (or the C++ equivalent) to have your program hang.

Please note that the C++ MPI bindings are no longer part of the standard and should not be used in the development of new software. Use the C bindings `MPI_Blabla` instead.

Comment: an other alternative to C++ MPI bindings is to use boostMPI. boostMPI is not part of the standard, but since some developers love it, i thought it was worth to be mentioned.

Comment: Boost.MPI is way behind the current standard in terms of operations, but, for what it implements, it is indeed a worthy OO wrapper around the MPI functionality.